# My erase junk mail is grayed out

Tags: mail.app, macos

The option to erase junk mail does not show up when I right click and in the menus it is grayed out. Any idea how to get it back.

I am running Yosemite, 10.10 on an iMac.

I couldn't find anything using google except someone else with the same problem and no answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try to set your settings to the what you see below, this may fix your issue. 
[image: Junk Mail Settings]

Comment: The 'Move it to the junk mailbox' setting enabled it.